# Cors Api Google

Tags: php, angularjs, api, cors

Tenho a seguinte requisição na API Google usando $http AngularJS:

```
$http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Porto Alegre&destinations=Sao Paulo&mode=driving&language=pt-BR&sensor=false');
```

O problema é que retorna o erro:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Porto%20Alegre&destinations=Sao%20Paulo&mode=driving&language=pt-BR&sensor=false.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Sei que é CORS ja tentei colocar este código no angular:

```
moduloVistoria.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
```

Mas nada funciona. Meu backend é em PHP e já coloquei:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Alguém pode me dizer o que pode estar ocorrendo ?

Comment: Você habilitou a API no Google Developers Console? Sugiro ler este documento (em inglês): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Comment: Versão pt_BR: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/?language=pt_BR

Comment: Fiz conforme o documento, mesmo assim não funciona. O documento não fala de cors.

Comment: Habilitei no console, gerei a key, mas o mesmo erro continua.

Comment: Quando habilito o allow control allow no chrome funciona

Comment: Alguem sabe o que pode ser ?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema acima? Poderia postar a solução? Grato!